# I'm stuck in the sky after respawning

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm a new Minecraft user. So I dug too deep into the void and died. Now I respawned in the sky and am stuck there. I tried dropping to the ground and I fall and it sounds like I hit ground, only I only fall a few feet below the clouds in midair. I had an awesome house build going. Is there a way to get back to the ground?

Comment: Is the world all black? Could you clarify with a screenshot? And you tried double-tapping space (after all, you can fly in creative mode)?

Comment: If you're in creative, can you grab a bucket of water, point straight down and hold right click? It might take a few goes but it should place the water and save you from the drop. It seems strange that you only hear the ground though, and don't see it. Hit F3 and check your coordinates, it might be worth editing the the world file to put something solid just underneath you

Answer (score 2):

I would teleport yourself down back to regular ground level. Using the command `/tp @p ~ 70 ~`. This command would teleport you close to ground level or maybe underneath ground level a few blocks. From there you can dig up or already be close to ground level. If this doesn't work you may be experiencing lag and I can't help with that.

Comment: Actually 64 is around the ground level. 70 will be in the air unless it is a mountain